# One question at a time?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have asked a question at [academia.stackexchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) with three sub-questions recently and I was told that it was not proper there. I just wonder if it is acceptable if one asks multiple (related) questions at math.stackexchange?

To mathematicians, if the answer is "no", that would not even make sense: I can always ask one single question of the form

> What is the ordered triple of the form $(X, Y, Z)$ such that $X$ is the answer to $X'$, $Y$ is the answer to $Y'$ and $Z$ is the answer to $Z'$?

Comment: See [Posting multiple questions as one?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?) (and also this [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/7132#7132). But if you mean several very closely related questions or several questions, which are all parts of the same problem, that would be another thing. (It is not always clear where to draw a line.)

Comment: BTW I don't think the title *Academia.stackexchange only allows me to ask one question at a time* describes your question well. From this title it looks like you have a question about academia.SE.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak, I have edited the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not ask multiple  questions within one. There is a closing reason for those (*too broad*) which says that the author should reduce the scope of the question. I see it has been applied to your [Academia question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/32407/).

The "clever" packaging into an ordered tuple would earn you nothing but a few additional downvotes along with closevotes.

Answer (score 6):

I generally dislike it when users ask multiple questions within a single question, and this is backed up by the [MSE faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/214632). I believe the main reasons for this are the following:

- If people provide answers of varying quality to the different parts (*e.g.*, exemplary solutions to questions (1) and (3), but a totally incorrect answer to question (2)), it makes *judging* the quality of these answers as a whole much more problematic.
- Such questions will often be more difficult to search for (*e.g.*, have an unfocused title, tags that only fit some of the questions), thereby decreasing their future utility.

I have been thinking of bringing up the idea of a custom close reason for these situations, but haven't found the time to fully develop it.